# How to default export a folder in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Having a dumb issue that I can't figure out

I have a folder called model and inside that folder there's `questions.ts`, `revokedtokens.ts` and `users.ts`. I'm trying to make it so that you can just

`import model from '../../model';`

and then use `model.questions.whatever()`

So I made an `index.ts` and this is inside

```
import questions from './questions.js';
import revokedtokens from './revokedtokens.js';
import users from './users.js';

export default {
  questions,
  revokedtokens,
  users,
};
```

But now I'm getting a TS issue that says
Directory import XX s not supported resolving ES modules imported from YY

I'm using **Node 14**

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./built",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020"],
    "module": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["./**/*", "./**/*.json"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "built"]
}
```

And I have `"type": "module",` inside my `package.json`

Example of `./model/questions.ts`

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import constants from '../libraries/constants.js';
import { regex } from '../utils.js';
import { QuestionsDocument } from '../definitions';

const questions = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: Object.values(constants.model.questions.type),
      lowercase: true,
      required: true,
    },
    question: {
      index: { unique: true },
      type: String,
      minlength: 3,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.model<QuestionsDocument>('questions', questions);
```

Comment: Did you write `import model from './model.js';`, `import model from './model';`, or `import model from './model/index.js';`? (And `.js` or `.ts`?)

Comment: I updated the question. The goal is `import model from '../../model';`

Comment: What [module resolution strategy](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) are you using, node? Can you show use your typescript config, please?

Comment: I'm using `node`. And I updated my question again! Thanks :)

Comment: try `import * as model from 'model'`

Comment: @bsapaka When I do that, I'm not able to use the properties inside of the `questions` or anything

Comment: try `export { questions, etc }` instead of `export default`

Comment: @bsapaka I tried that and I still get the same error =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing Module to

`"module": "CommonJS",`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
import questions from './questions';
import revokedtokens from './revokedtokens';
import users from './users';

const model = {
  questions,
  revokedtokens,
  users,
};

export default model;
```

Comment: Still the same error :(
I added what my questions.ts looks like in case that helps?

Comment: I just edited my answer. Just export default the model variable so that we can import it as: import model from "../../model"

Comment: @TuanDucVo But now it's doing exactly the same as the OPs existing code.

Comment: Not sure why you are importing the .js. Can you remove .js in the import statements and try again?

Comment: E.g: 
import questions from './questions';
import revokedtokens from './revokedtokens';
import users from './users';

Comment: I'd like to not have to manually import everything @TuanDucVo